# не отображается сообщение

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

пишу программу на андройд не могу понять почему мой код не выводится в "textView"

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
            String json_url;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                json_url ="myurl";
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(json_url);
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                        {
                            stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
                        }
                        bufferedReader.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView.setText(result);
            }
        }
```

в textView должен выводится мой "result" после нажатия на кнопку. Мой текст обновляется, но остается пустым. Нужное сообщение не выводится не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: подебажьте. что в `result` приходит?

Comment: Последнее предложение плохо отформатировано. Попробуйте добавить запятых - пока что плохо понятно что вы хотите сказать.